# Чи можна альтернативно вживати формулювання "на Україні"?

Tags: вживання-слів, правопис, розмовна-українська, прийменники

Зауважу, що *питання не в тому, яка з форм "в Україні" чи "на Україні" є правильною. Суть полягає в іншому: чи можна паралельно вживати форму "на Україні", тобто **чи має вона право на існування хоча б у розмовній мові?***

Досить часто зустрічається формулювання "на Україні", зокрема, у популярній пісні [Лише у нас на Україні](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57cp_UKDLg4) та у розмовній українській мові.

У поезії Шевченка зустрічаємо: «Серед степу широкого на Вкраїні милій».

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%96) з цього приводу сказано таке:

> В українській мові деякими мовознавцями грамотним вважається лише
>   вживання «в Україні», прийменник «на» вживається тоді, коли не
>   говориться про окрему незалежну територію, чи мається на увазі острів,
>   наприклад: «На Волинь, на Закарпаття, на Кубу», але «В Польщу, в
>   Росію», «в Галичині».

Всупереч цьому, численні сайти містять інформацію, що правильно буде вживати прийменник "в" - "в Україні". Таке можена знайти [тут](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/41.htm) та [тут](https://tsn.ua/video/video-novini/uroki-ukrayinskoyi-yak-pravilna-kazati-v-ukrayini-chi-na-ukrayini.html).

*У зв`язку з цим виникає питання, чи має право на існування формулювання "на Україні", окрім "в Україні", у сучасній українській мові?*

Comment: Мені здається, що відповідь на інше запитання не лише (1) стверджує, що *так, така форма має право на існування*, але і (2) показує, у якому са́ме контексті така форма може (і навіть повинна) використовуватися. Хіба не так?

Comment: Перечитала відповідь. Справді, не помітила одразу, дякую.